# Java:: Converting ArrayList Primitive into Array of Number class?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

If let say i have;

```
ArrayList <Double> myV = new ArrayList <Double>();
myV.add(12.2); 
myV.add(3.2); 
myV.add(5.00); 

// this is error
Number[] youV = myV.toArray();
```

the below code is error when I compiled it. What should I do then to convert the ArrayList into Number of arrays type?

How to convert them into **Number[]** ?
And lastly, is this code list safe for us to use, if I apply this code 
inside Android?

Comment: What do mean by *safe*?

Comment: in terms of memory usage. Because Android device is a mobile (small) device instead of laptop computer. @kocko

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please make some edits.

Comment: if its a simple list then you can use String numbers[] myV.toArray(new String[myV.size()]); but there are certain limitations also on this new array, need to know the requirement of the array

Comment: Android Devices generally have RAM in the range of 0.5 to 3 GB and each application typically has a dedicated heap of 64 MB or more. I don't understand in what way you think your code will be limited by running on Android? It's not an embedded device from the 1990s we are talking about...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils thanks for clarifying but my first case (first question) hasn't been answered. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: `Double ` isn't a primitive type, but `double` is. I think what you mean is this: `ArrayList <double> myV = new ArrayList <double>();`. You can onvert each double item to Double wraper class, then add it to `Number[] youV`.

Comment: @ChakerMallek And just to be precise: primitive types and generics don't work together; so it is **not** possible to have `ArrayList<double>`. And assuming that the author has really a "memory savings" issue (which most likely, he does not have), one should be careful about going forth and back with primitive types and their wrapper objects. An ArrayList with Double objects comes with quite some overhead (compared to a plain double[] array).

Comment: @Jägermeister sorry I forgot that  primitive data types cannot be placed into Java collections. After we box the primitive values, we can put them into collections.So isn't the OP question misleading "Converting `ArrayList Primitive` into Array of Number class" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do what you need.

```
Number[] result = new Number[myV.size()];
myV.toArray(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, You can convert them like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Double> myV = new ArrayList<Double>();
    myV.add(12.2);
    myV.add(3.2);
    myV.add(5.00);
    Number[] target = new Number[myV.size()];
    myV.toArray(target);
    System.out.println(target[0]);
}
```